# Why is there an issue with the mentioned alarm clock problem?

Tags: python

Problem-

Given a day of the week encoded as 0=Sun, 1=Mon, 2=Tue, ...6=Sat, and a boolean indicating if we are on vacation, return a string of the form "7:00" indicating when the alarm clock should ring. Weekdays, the alarm should be "7:00" and on the weekend it should be "10:00". Unless we are on vacation -- then on weekdays it should be "10:00" and weekends it should be "off".

Soln:

```
def alarm_clock(day, vacation):
  if day>=1 and day<=5 and not vacation:
    return '7:00'
  elif day==0 or day==6 and vacation:
    return 'off'
  elif day==0 or day==6 and not vacation or day>=1 and day<=5 and vacation:
    return '10:00'
```

For the problem When I am inputting alarm_clock(0, False) it is giving 'off' as output and not '10:00'

Can someone pls highlight where the issue is?

Comment: It's operator precedence. Try grouping your conditions with some parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Add parentheses to your expression to group logical statements.

```
def alarm_clock(day, vacation):
  if (day>=1 and day<=5) and not vacation:
    return '7:00'
  elif (day==0 or day==6) and vacation:
    return 'off'
  elif ((day==0 or day==6) and not vacation) or ((day>=1 and day<=5) and vacation):
    return '10:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the order of the elif statements or the `or` with the `and` usage.

One solution:

Grouping the or statement

```py
def alarm_clock(day, vacation):
  if day>=1 and day<=5 and not vacation:
    return '7:00'
  elif (day==0 or day==6) and vacation:
    return 'off'
  elif (day==0 or day==6) and not vacation or day>=1 and day<=5 and vacation:
    return '10:00'
```

Second solution:

Changing which statement goes where

```py
def alarm_clock(day, vacation):
  if day>=1 and day<=5 and not vacation:
    return '7:00'
  elif day==0 or day==6 and not vacation or day>=1 and day<=5 and vacation:
    return '10:00'
  elif day==0 or day==6 and vacation:
    return 'off'
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
def alarm_clock(day, vacation):
  if day>=1 and day<=5 and not vacation:
    return '7:00'
  elif (day==0 or day==6) and vacation:
    return 'off'
  elif (day==0 or day==6) and (not vacation) or (day>=1 and day<=5) and vacation:
    return '10:00'
```

You basically need to group them in parentheses `()`